# Python passing void pointer as parameter to C function (SWIG, Numpy)

Tags: python, c, numpy, pointers, swig

I need to pass a pointer from Python to a C function. I'm currently trying with SWIG but I'm ready to switch to anything that will solve my issue :)

To simplify my problem, I wrote this empty C function in SWIG:

```
extern void myvoidp(void *p);
```

I've setup my .i and .c files, all compile fine and work in Python.

I'd like to pass a Numpy array. I can get the memory address of the Numpy data like this

```
>>> anp = array([1,2,3])
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> anp.ctypes.data
40546992
```

I can cast it to a void * like this with ctypes and numpy:

```
>>> anp.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p)
c_void_p(40546992)
```

I've tried endless variants. Whatever I do, when I invoke my C function I get this error.

```
>>> myswig.myvoidp(anp.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: in method 'myvoidp', argument 1 of type 'void *'
```

I can't figure out how to write a Python / numpy statement that allows me to (simply) pass a pointer to my C function. :-(

Comment: Does `myswig.myvoidp(ctypes.c_void_p(40546992))` work? If not, then you can eliminate `numpy` from the question

Comment: Good idea. Yes, that yields the same error, so numpy is not playing in. I've found a way to make it work in ctypes though, I guess because in ctypes I specify that I want to pass a void pointer as the first arg.

Comment: So to be clear, it works using ctypes to call the function, but not swig?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I believe that's because in ctypes I need to define the expected argument first. Which I do like this:    self.clib_myvoidp.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p].   So somehow SWIG must mess up the definition of the void * type.

Comment: Hi, Is this possible without numpy.i ? Would like to convert any python object to a void pointer and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to receive a pointer to the data of the NumPy array, so that you can access the array elements from C.  NumPy ships with [SWIG support](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.html) which is easy and convenient to use.  Just download [`numpy.i`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/tools/swig/numpy.i) and place it in your project directory.

Just change the signature of the C function from `(void *p)` to `(double *data, int length)` and apply the NumPy typemap.

**`test.i`**

```c
%module example
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include <stdio.h>

void myvoidp(double *data, int length) {
    printf("data = [ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        printf("%f ", data[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
import_array();
%}

%apply (double* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double *data, int length)}
void myvoidp(double *data, int length);
```

**`test.py`**

```python
from example import myvoidp
from numpy import array

anp = array([1,2,3])
myvoidp(anp)
```

Example invocation:

```
$ swig -python test.i
$ clang -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/python3.6m/ -fPIC -shared -o _example.so test_wrap.c -lpython3.6m
$ python3 test.py 
data = [ 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 ]
```

Comment: Cool. I will try that out. Thank you :)

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain where my answer is lacking?

Comment: I dont think that was me, but I'm a noob here anyway &  don't know if it was a freak mouse click ;)I've voted you one up JIC.